# PyGears hdlgen generates top level module with DTI interfaces, Vivado is expecting Verilog which does not support this feature

Tags: python, verilog, system-verilog, pygears

I made my module whish looks like this

```python
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Fixp, Tuple
from pygears.lib import add, qround, saturate, drv, collect
from pygears.sim import sim
from pygears.hdl import hdlgen

@gear
def adder(data: Tuple[Fixp[10, 32], Fixp[10, 32]]):
  return add(data[0],data[1]) \
    | qround (fract=21) \
    | saturate(t=Fixp[11, 32])
    
hdlgen('/adder',outdir='./Example1/adder_hdl',copy_files='True')
```

Now, my top level module interfaces are DTI interfaces

```systemverilog
module adder(
    input logic clk,
    input logic rst,

    dti.consumer data, // (q10.22, q10.22) (64)
    dti.producer dout // q11.21 (32)

);
```

Since Vivado is expecting top level wrapper to be in Verilog is there any way to tell PyGears to convert top level interfaces into standard ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Use parameter **toplang** for hdlgen function and set it to 'v' for Verilog.
Something like this

```python
hdlgen('/adder',outdir='./Example1/adder_hdl',copy_files='True',toplang='v')
```

This will produce top wrepper called adder_v_wrap and interface will have Verilog ports

```verilog
module adder_v_wrap
(
    input clk,
    input rst,

    output reg  data_ready,
    input  wire data_valid,
    input  wire [63:0] data_data,
    input  wire         dout_ready,
    output reg          dout_valid,
    output wire  [31:0] dout_data

);
```